# Node.js + Kafka + AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I have set up Kafka on the AWS architecture.

Now, I need locally, on my PC created script in Node.js that could allow me to send a message to the Kafka producer.

And now the hard part comes:
I've tried different libraries such as `kafka-node`, `kafkajs`, but from my understanding, this works only in case, when kafka is not on the non-cloud server. 
Also, I've tried to play with `aws-sdk`, but I can't see any option there to send any message to the producer.

Do you have any idea what to use, and how to configure such flow local -> aws env with .pem key-> kafka producer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you could show your code and/or errors, then you'll likely get a more clear answer.

Comment: Also make sure all the appropriate ports are open in the security group for your IP.

Answer (score 0):

> this works only in case, when kafka is not on the non-cloud server

This is likely a false assumption. It's not clear if you are using Amazon MSK, but even that doesn't use .pem files, and `aws-sdk` is not a Kafka producer application itself.

In most cases, simply ensuring that [your Kafka cluster is configured with the correct `advertised.listeners`](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) and your producer (and conusmer) uses an external address of the `bootstrap.servers` is enough.